# How do I show that the sup norm metric is a metric for $\Bbb{R}^n$? (the triangular inequality specifically)

Tags: analysis

I am not sure how to approach such inequality. I have shown the other 3 requirement for the sup norm to be a metric for $\Bbb{R}^n$.

For $x,y,z\in \Bbb{R}^n$, we need to show that

$$\sup\{\lvert x_i - z_i\rvert \}\leq \sup\{\lvert x_i - y_i \rvert \} + \sup\{\lvert y_i - z_i \rvert \}\text{ for }i\in \{1,2,...,n\}$$

My thought is that this should be related to the cauchy schwarz inequality. But not sure how to start. since C.S is in the series form not in the supremum form.

Thanks for help

Comment: Hint: note that $$\sup_i (|x_i - y_i| + |y_i - z_i|) \le \sup_{i,j} (|x_i - y_i| + |y_j - z_j|) =  \sup_i |x_i - y_i| + \sup_j |y_j - z_j|.$$

Comment: Let me know if you'd like a full answer.

Comment: May I ask why the absolute value is not necessary? I am following the textbook definition where it has the absolute value in there, also since we are considering $R^n$ shouldn't there be negative numbers? Sorry this is probably a trivial question but I am trying to learn. Thank you so much for helping me

Comment: What I meant in my deleted comment is that, in order to show the above inequality is true, you shouldn't need any properties specific to absolute values, as this holds for more general functions. If you are computing the supremum of the sum of two functions, this will generally be less than if you compute the suprema of the functions separately and add the result. The condition that $x = y$ when maximising $f(x) + g(y)$ is a restriction, and hence yields a smaller result than when maximising $f(x) + g(y)$ with $x$ and $y$ unrestricted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Lemma:** Suppose $S$ is a set and $f, g : S \to \Bbb{R}$. Then
>   $$\sup_{s \in S} (f(s) + g(s)) \le \sup_{s \in S} f(s) + \sup_{t \in S} g(t).$$

*Proof:* Suppose $S, f, g$ are as in the statement. Note that, for any $s_0 \in S$, we have
\begin{align*}
f(s_0) \le \sup_{s \in S} f(s) \\
g(s_0) \le \sup_{t \in S} g(t),
\end{align*}
hence
$$f(s_0) + g(s_0) \le \sup_{s \in S} f(s) + \sup_{t \in S} g(t).$$
That is, $\sup_{s \in S} f(s) + \sup_{t \in S} g(t)$ is an upper bound for $\{f(s) + g(s) : s \in S\}$, hence
$$\sup_{s \in S} (f(s) + g(s)) \le \sup_{s \in S} f(s) + \sup_{t \in S} g(t).$$

---

In particular, apply the lemma with $S = \{1, \ldots, n\}$, $f : i \mapsto |x_i - y_i|$, and $g : j \mapsto |y_j - z_j|$. Then,
$$\sup_i (|x_i - y_i| + |y_i - z_i|) \le \sup_i |x_i - y_i| + \sup_j |y_j - z_j|.$$
Note that, by triangle inequality, we have $|x_i - z_i| \le |x_i - y_i| + |y_i - z_i|$, and hence taking the supremum of both sides, we get
$$\sup_i |x_i - z_i| \le \sup_i (|x_i - y_i| + |y_i - z_i|) \le \sup_i |x_i - y_i| + \sup_j |y_j - z_j|,$$
which is what we needed!

Comment: Thank you so much!